# getchar or cin.get() not working in dev cpp

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I wrote a program in which I want to take input from user and if any key other than 'N' or 'n' is pressed, program will display "HELLO WORLD" as the output , otherwise it will display "Exiting " message and exit. The below program is working in Linux but not in Dev-cpp windows. Even after changing the cin.get() to getchar() is not working. The program does not wait for user input.

I added system("pause") before cin.get() also but then it always goes into else part of the program whenever a key is pressed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch ;

    cout << "Press any key to continue, " << endl;
    cout << "Press N or n to exit " << endl;

    ch = cin.get();

    if(ch == 'N' || ch == 'n')
    {
        cout << "Exiting " << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use `cin >> ch;` instead.

Comment: As explained here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ cin.get() returns an integer, so I was just wondering, does this code compile at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char ch ;
    cout << "Press any key to continue, " << endl;
    cout << "Press N or n to exit " << endl;
    cin.get(ch);
    if(ch == 'N' || ch == 'n'){
        cout << "Exiting " << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could try cin.get(ch), instead of ch = cin.get().